# How can I avoid duplicate @JsonProperty annotations with an immutable object and non-matching property name?

Tags: java, jackson

The json I'm dealing with uses underscores in the property names, but I wish to keep camel case in Java. Further, I'm using immutable style POJOs, since that's a best practice our team has long adopted.

Everything works fine if I put duplicate @JsonProperty annotations in the constructor and on the getter, but this adds a lot of unnecessary bloat (in our classes, we have a couple dozen properties.) Is there a way to tell Jackson exactly once how to transform the Java property name to the JSON property name?

```
 public class Foo {

     public final String someProperty;

     @JsonCreator
     public Foo(@JsonProperty("some_property") someProperty) {
         this.someProperty = someProperty;
     }

     @JsonProperty("some_property")
     public String getSomeProperty() {
         return someProperty;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Not part of the question, but you need a type for the `someProperty` constructor parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the naming convention used for JSON. In this case you need SNAKE_CASE. It will convert `someProperty` field to `"some_property": ""` JSON. Then you don't need the @JsonProperty in the property.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
```

In this case, in Foo, you need to provide the field in the constructor, what requires the @JsonProperty in the constructor params:

```
public class Foo {

   public final String someProperty;

   @JsonCreator
   public Foo(@JsonProperty("some_property") String someProperty) {
       this.someProperty = someProperty;
   }

   public String getSomeProperty() {
       return someProperty;
   }
}
```

At least you can get rid of one of the annotations.